# How can I make a schedule table for instructor from tables created

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database, erd

**Problem**

I need to make scheduale for instructor in training center.

I created tables but relation I cannot do.

What relation do I make between instructor_course table class table and section table? (Must I have a foreign key from table class and table section? Must I add ClassID FK from table class And SectionID from table section to table Inst_Courses Table?)

**Table details**

I need to show schedule for instructor courses within week from Sunday to Thursday.

E.g. *In Sunday from 2 - 4 clock Instructor Michel give C# Course in ClassRoom A 
Section B*

So I created following tables :

```
Courses (like c#,access,SQL)
Instructor(Teacher)
Int_Courses
Class( Lab or class room)
Section(group of student take courses classified to a,b,c,c2)
```

I already made relations between Instructor table and Courses table many to many in third table Inst_Courses table.

**Result expected**

[image]

**Database Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses](
    [CourseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ClassID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructor](
    [InstructorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IstructorName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Instructor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InstructorID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstructorCourses](
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InstructorID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.InstructorCourses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC,
    [InstructorID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Section](
    [SecID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SecName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Section] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SecID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructor_Class](
    [ClassID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InstructorID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Instructor_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassID] ASC,
    [InstructorID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Too broad.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: can you post db schema and some sample data? and what result you expect

Comment: Please explain what a (student?) group is, what a (class?) section is and what your image's table tells us. Write as if we do not understand how things are organized, because we don't. Please give DDL for as many tables as you can. PS Your sentence about Michel doesn't agree with the table.

Comment: You are not clear. Please show as much of your table as possible. Please describe what you want to do. What is stopping you from designing the table? Doyou mean you want to design a *report* that looks like the image? Or a *table* that contains that information? PS "I created tables but relation cannot do." is not clear. What is a "relation"? Do you mean "table"? Do you mean "relationship"? That is often but wrongly used for "foreign key". Do you mean "foreign key"?

Answer (score 0):

**A table for this report**

This report only works if 'Michel' identifies one instructor. Otherwise either you need multiple sub-reports for one weekday-timeslot intersection or you need multiple reports.

Each non-blank sub-report at a row and column of your report tells you: `instructor Michel teaches course`*`C`*`in classroom`*`CR`*`to section`*`S`*`for department`*`D`*.

So the report tells you the same thing overall as a table holding the rows where: `instructor Michel teaches course`*`C`*`in classroom`*`CR`*`to section`*`S`*`for department`*`D`*`in timeslot`*`TS`*`on weekday`*`WD`*. Notice how we take each column and row of a multi-dimensional report like this and add a column for it to the table for each multi-dimensional sub-report where they intersect.

Probably you want a table telling you the same thing as all reports for all instructors: `instructor`*`I`*`teaches course`*`C`*`in classroom`*`CR`*`to section`*`S`*`for department`*`D`*`in timeslot`*`TS`*`on weekday`*`WD`*. Notice how we take a parameter in the title and add a column for it to the table.

(Now we don't need to worry about whether Michel identifies one instructor.)

**A first design for this report**

Instructor names are probably non-unique or non-permanent. So add ids to names and report titles. You probably have more data about instructors, courses and departments. So have tables for them. Apparently a section number is only unique within a course.

```
-- instructor ID is named NAME and ...
Instructor(id, name, ...)
    CK(id)
-- course NAME ...
Course(name, ...)
    CK (name)
-- department NAME ...
Department(name, ...)
    CK (name)
-- course C_NAME has section S_NUMBER
Course_Has_Section(C_name, S_number)
    CK (C_name, S_number)
    FK(C_name) to Course
-- instructor I_id teaches course C_NAME in classroom CR_NAME to section S_NUMBER 
--     for department D_NAME in timeslot TS_NAME on weekday WD_NAME
Weekly_Lecture(I_id, C_name, CR_name, S_number, D_name, TS_name, WD_name)
    FK(I_id) to Instructor
    FK(C_name, S_number) to Course_Has_Section
    FK(D_name) to Department
```

Your design details will differ. Maybe courses and/or departments have unique codes. Then you might use them as FKs. Then add a table. Apparently a section can be active, whatever that means.

**CKs and Normalizing**

A given instructor, timeslot & weekday can only have one weekly lecture. But no smaller subset of those does. So we have `Weekly_Lecture CK(I_id, TS_name, WD_name)`. A given course, section, timeslot & weekday can only have one weekly lecture. But no smaller subset of those does. So we have `Weekly_Lecture CK(C_name, S_number, TS_name, WD_name)`. A given classroom, timeslot & weekday can only have one weekly lecture. But no smaller subset of those does. So we have `Weekly_Lecture CK(CR_name, TS_name, WD_name)`.

Maybe a given course can only be taught for one department? Maybe a given section number can only be taught by a given instructor? By identifying all FDs (functional dependencies) we determine all CKs (candidate keys). Then *normalization* uses these to possibly suggest "better" choices for base tables.