# How to join section table with ERDigram

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

**Problem**

**Which is correct when join section table with class table  OR with course table  OR with instructor Table .**

**Details**

section is group of student classified to ( aa,bb,cc )can take one course or more courses.

section can teach in one or more class(lab or class room) .

Instructor can teach to more sections and section can have more instructor
raltion is many to many and made in third table Inst_Course

My ER diagram as following :

[section table join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMvL6.jpg)

Database Schema as following :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructor](
    [InstructorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InstructorName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Instructor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InstructorID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course](
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CourseName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Course] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ClassID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Section](
    [SectionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SectionName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Section] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SectionID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inst_Course](
    [InstID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Inst_Course] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InstID] ASC,
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course_Class](
    [ClassID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Fromtime] [int] NULL,
    [Totime] [int] NULL,
    [day] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Course_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassID] ASC,
    [CourseID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Relation between tables as following :**

Class table and courses table has many to many relation ship in tableCourse_Class .

Instructor table and courses table has relation many to many in table
Inst_Course .

**Section is have many to many with instructor table and course table and class table
which is correct for join section with instructor or course or class**

**Notes :this diagram not have student courses table because the goal from diagram is design schedule for instructor .**

**sample data**

[Sample data to table Course_Class for instructor schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnHqJ.jpg)

**join between tables as following :**

```
SELECT     dbo.Class.ClassName, dbo.Course_Class.CourseID, dbo.Course_Class.Fromtime, dbo.Course_Class.Totime, dbo.Course_Class.day, dbo.Course.CourseName, 
                      dbo.Inst_Course.InstID, dbo.Inst_Course.CourseID AS Expr3, dbo.Instructor.InstructorID, dbo.Instructor.InstructorName
FROM         dbo.Class INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Course_Class ON dbo.Class.ClassID = dbo.Course_Class.ClassID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Course ON dbo.Course_Class.CourseID = dbo.Course.CourseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Inst_Course ON dbo.Course.CourseID = dbo.Inst_Course.CourseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Instructor ON dbo.Inst_Course.InstID = dbo.Instructor.InstructorID
WHERE     (dbo.Inst_Course.InstID = 1)
```

**Question is :Actually what i need is which table must join with section table class or course or instructor tables**

**Update**

Class in my case represent classroom or lab meaning class is the place teach courses in it
Section :(group of student)represent who teaches .

I can take course c# in class 1 meaning lab 1 or lab 2 or lab 3
and in lab1 i can get course c# OR c++ OR java in my case .

Here i treat with section to represent group of students .

section can teach more courses c# and c++ and java .

c# course can have more section aa,bb,cc .

**Update2**

**student participate in one section only and cannot more section meaning relation one to many .**

**relation between section and class is many to many because section aa can take course c# in class a and class bb**

**and class bb can have course c# and c++**

**if you mean by session is course you are right .**

**Courses teaches in more classes in different times from 9-11,11-1,1-3,3-4.30
in different classes .**

**courses include more sections and every section can have more course**

Comment: what is the question? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You've not given sufficient information nor asked a clear question. 1) how are these tables to be related to one another?  E.g., where is your `InstructorCourses` table which says which instructors teach which courses?  Where is your `StudentCourses` table which records which students are in which course?  At that point, you're likely going to be doing a `cross join` between all 3 tables (so, a cartesian product) with `outer joins` to those 3 tables to fill in the blanks.

Comment: According to relation between tables it found in diagram above

Comment: Im sorry it will not repeated again i ask for all questions above

Comment: I modified my original post

Comment: Actually what i need is which table must join with section table class or course or instructor tables

Comment: I modified my post are there are any thing not clear

Comment: Please do not "update" your post. *Rewrite it*. All the parts that are not clear are still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

OK, updated based upon your update, I'd suggest you have the following structures:

```
create table dbo.Instructors (
    InstructorID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkc_Instructors
            primary key clustered ( InstructorID ) ,
    InstructorName nvarchar(48) not null ,
        constraint uni_InstructorName@Instructors
            unique nonclustered ( InstructorName )
    )

create table dbo.Courses (
    CourseID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkc_Courses
            primary key clustered ( CourseID ) ,
    CourseName nvarchar(48) not null ,
        constraint uni_CourseName@Courses
            unique nonclustered ( CourseName )
    )

create table dbo.ClassRooms (
    ClassRoomID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkc_ClassRooms
            primary key clustered ( ClassRoomID ) ,
    ClassRoomName nvarchar(48) not null ,
        constraint uni_ClassRoomName@ClassRooms
            unique nonclustered ( ClassRoomName )
    )

create table dbo.Sections (
    SectionID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkc_Sections
            primary key clustered ( SectionID ) ,
    CourseID int not null ,
        constraint fk_CourseID@Sections
            foreign key ( CourseID )
            references dbo.Courses ( CourseID ) ,
    SectionName nvarchar(48) not null ,
        constraint uni_SectionName@Sections
            unique nonclustered ( SectionName )
    )

create table dbo.StudentSections (
    StudentSectionID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkn_StudentSections
            primary key nonclustered ( StudentSectionID ) ,
    StudentID int not null ,
        constraint fk_StudentID@StudentSections
            foreign key ( StudentID )
            references dbo.Students ( StudentID ) ,
    SectionID int not null ,
        constraint fk_SectionID@StudentSections
            foreign key ( SectionID )
            references dbo.Sections ( SectionID ) ,
        constraint uci_StudentID_SectionID@StudentSections
            unique clustered ( StudentID , SectionID )
    )

create table dbo.SectionClassRooms (
    SectionClassRoomID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkn_SectionClassRooms
            primary key nonclustered ( SectionClassRoomID ) ,
    SectionID int not null ,
        constraint fk_SectionID@SectionClassRooms
            foreign key ( SectionID )
            references dbo.Sections ( SectionID ) ,
    ClassRoomID int not null ,
        constraint fk_ClassRoomID@SectionClassRooms
            foreign key ( ClassRoomID )
            references dbo.ClassRooms ( ClassRoomID ) ,
        constraint uci_SectionID_ClassRoomID@SectionClassRooms
            unique clustered ( SectionID , ClassRoomID )
    )

create table dbo.InstructorSections (
    InstructorSectionID int identity(1,1) not null ,
        constraint pkn_InstructorSections
            primary key nonclustered ( InstructorSectionID ) ,
    InstructorID int not null ,
        constraint fk_InstructorID@InstructorSections
            foreign key ( InstructorID )
            references dbo.Instructors ( InstructorID ) ,
    SectionID int not null ,
        constraint fk_SectionID@InstructorSections
            foreign key ( SectionID )
            references dbo.Sections ( SectionID ) ,
        constraint uci_InstructorID_SectionID@InstructorSections
            unique clustered ( InstructorID , SectionID )
    )
```

What this says:

- `Instructors` are their own entities, with each `instructor` having a unique name.
- `Courses` are similar, with uniqueness on their name.
- `ClassRooms`, ditto.
- `Sections` must be a section of a `Course` and cannot exist in isolation.
- `Students` participate in one or more `Sections`.
- `Sections` may take place in one or more `ClassRooms` (if this is not true, then we need to make `ClassRoomID` an attribute of each `Section`, rather than putting this in its own table `SectionClassRooms`).
- An `Instructor` may teach many `Sessions` and also a `Session` may be taught by multiple `Instructors` (if this is not the case, then `InstructorID` should be an attribute of `Sessions`).

Obviously, you're going to have a few more fields in some of these, as needed.  For example: when do the Sessions take place?  Does a Session have the same time regardless of the classroom in which it takes place?  There are nuances here, I'm sure.

Lastly, I'd encourage you to review the `clustered` vs `nonclustered` indexing, as this should be optimized for how your information will be retrieved.  Not critical, but I made a stab at how I thought it should work, not knowing your application requirements.

I'll modify this again if needed.

Comment: section table represent group of student teaching specified course classified to AA,BB,CC.in university when student go to me and ask i have course c# when and where i will ask him firstly you are following to which section and depend on section he tell me i can tell him where is the course and when and which place

Comment: I update my original post about the points not clear.and i thank you to try to help me

Comment: @ahmedsalah Updated the answer. Let me know if it needs refinement.

Comment: I updated my original post see last line under update section on my original post

Comment: student participate in one section only and cannot more section meaning relation one to many .

Comment: relation between section and class is many to many because section aa can take course c# in class a and class bb

Comment: I update original post by this comments you can see it now

Answer (score 0):

This design seems to arise from the relationship/table in [this question you recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810614/how-can-i-make-schedule-table-for-instructor-from-tables-created). (Unfortunately both questions are extremely unclear.) From my answer:

> Probably you want a table telling you the same thing as all reports for all instructors: `instructor`*`I`*`teaches course`*`C`*`in classroom`*`CR`*`to section`*`S`*`for department`*`D`*`in timeslot`*`TS`*`on weekday`*`WD`*.

I told you you should learn *normalization*:

> By identifying all FDs (functional dependencies) we determine all CKs (candidate keys). Then *normalization* uses these to possibly suggest "better" choices for base tables.

In that question and in this question *it is not possible to express the big table as a join of smaller tables*.

A prerequisite for decomposing a table into smaller ones, ie for joining smaller ones to get it, is that the statement that a row makes when it is in the big table can be expressed as the AND of the statements of the smaller tables.

Apparently `Course_Class` holds rows that make a true statement from `course COURSEID is taught in classroom CLASSID from FROMTIME to TOTIME on day WEEKDAY`. Apparently `Inst_Course` holds rows that make a true statement from `instructor INSTID teaches course COURSEID`.

Maybe you want the rows where `instructor INSTID teaches course COURSEID in classroom CLASSID from FROMTIME to TOTIME on day WEEKDAY`. If every instructor that teaches a course teaches every lecture of it then you can join `Course_Class` and `Inst_Course` to get this. That seems very unlikely. So more likely, this cannot be rephrased using the AND of smaller statements. So you can't get this table from joining smaller tables.

Maybe you want the rows where `instructor INSTID teaches section SECTIONID of course COURSEID in classroom CLASSID from FROMTIME to TOTIME on day WEEKDAY`. Then, similarly, adding a `Course_Section` table for `course COURSEID has section SECTIONID` is no help unless *also* every section of a course is taught in every lecture for it.

The information in the separate tables just doesn't collectively tell you what that big tables do. (Although it happens that here the smaller tables can be probably be generated from the big tables.)

You need to learn about (FKs & CKs &) *normalization*, which replaces big tables by smaller ones that join back to them.