# Database design for banks

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have Banks, Products and Rate_Term entity in the database.

Each bank has multiple products like Short Term Deposit, Long Term Deposit. And each product has different Rate Terms like 30 days, 60 days, 90 days, 180 days and 360 days.

And everyday Rates under Bank, Product and Rate_Term will change. So the rates for today will look like below:

[image]

I have designed the tables like below:

### Bank

- id
- code
- name

### Product

- id
- code
- name

### Bank_Product

- id
- bank_id
- product_id

### Rate_Term

- id
- Term (30, 60, 90....)

### Rates (For everyday rates)

- id
- bank_product_id (From Bank_Product table)
- rate_term_id (From Rate_Term table)
- date
- rate (in percentage)

Is my design OK?
Should I have another table for Bank_Product_Rate_Term?

Thanks in advance,
Arefin

Answer (score 0):

Your report (from some date) has a rate for a given bank-product-term triplet. So a rate can depend on its bank, product and term. You propose a table with (ignoring dates) (bank-product)-term-rate triplets. That gives a rate depending on bank, product and term. So your current design is in general adequate. This is still so when you add dates.

This is exactly the issue in recent questions [How can I make a schedule table for instructor from tables created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810614/how-can-i-make-schedule-table-for-instructor-from-tables-created#) and [How to join section table with ERDigram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40874193/3404097). (You even both have an initial report that has entries from one dimension in a grid with one dimension varying across the top, subrows from multiple other dimensions varying through the rows and one dimension that isn't actually in the report.)

It is good to have a permanent unique identifier in use in the business outside the database. But your *codes* seem to do this. And *terms* are identified by their number of days. And bank-product code pairs identify bank-product pairs. So it's not clear why/that you need *any* ids:

```
Bank(code, name) -- PK (code)
Product(code, name) -- PK (code)
Bank_Product(bank_code, product_code)
    -- PK (bank_code, product_code)
    -- FK (bank_code) references Bank (code)
    -- FK (product_code) references Product (code)
Rate(bank_code, product_code, term, date, rate)
    -PK (bank_code, product_code, term, date, rate)
    -FK (bank_code, product_code) references Bank_Product
```

(If terms are not always just the ones in Rate then you also need `Term(term) -- PK (term)` and a `FK (term) references Term` in Rate.)

PS: There is an interesting *constraint* on a table representing a report like yours if (as is consistent with your example report) it has a grid entry from one dimension for every possible combination of (subrow) values from some other dimensions. The constraint is that projecting the table on all those other dimensions gives the join of the tables contributing those values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @Arefin Thanks comments are discouraged, but upvoting (click triangle/arrow) and accepting (click check mark) are encouraged instead.